# 7zip error codes

Tags: 7-zip, runtime-error

While trying to extract a file from a split archive, it failed consistently at 61% with

> Unknown error -2147024891

This error code seems to appear only a single other time anywhere, [here](https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2017/01/22/%23ubuntu.html). And there it also wasn't explained.

This particular error message seemed to have been caused by one of the partial files being corrupt, but the error message was extremely unhelpful in figuring that out.

**Is there a proper documentation on how these error codes are generated, what they mean and how to fix them?**

<sub>Clarification: I do not need a solution for my particular case, it was already fixed by re-downloading some parts. I'm asking for a general documentation what these codes mean.</sub>

Comment: Update: I tested the archive with `7z t Archive\ name.zip.001` and it told me that there's 1 archive with errors. Sadly it didn't tell me which one. I now hope that it originally zipped and split the files in alphabetical order, in that case I would "only" have to re-download archives 95-104. If I'm right, the error should hopefully be pretty close to the end of archive #101. But maybe it also zipped in any arbitrary order, in that case I'm out of luck. Would be nice if I could test which of the archives is broken.

Comment: The simplest way to determine what part is broken (if 7zip do not report this) is to move a half of last parts to another folder and try to extract. If broken part was moved you will obtain a message like 'need the next part' (and you must be sure these parts are not broken), if not - you will obtain the same error as now... Then move a quarter (if first - back, if second - from) and repeat... 9 iterations will give the exact number of a part you must re-download. *maybe it also zipped in any arbitrary order* No, it was splitted during archiving with numbering in order.

Comment: -2147024891 == 0x80070005 means Access Denied – on Windows.

Comment: @DanielB I just looked at the description of the `p7zip-gui` package and it seems to not be a Windows application (ran with Mono, Wine or barely ported), it seems to be a proper application, written from scratch for Linux. So I would see no reason to get a Windows error message.

Comment: You ever have not said is this archive solid or not... if it is solid you MUST obtain correct all parts from the beginning till the file you need to extract. And if not you most likely need in all previous parts too. The parts 7zip creates are simply splitted parts without any header (the whole archive can be re-created by a common binary copy into one file in proper order).

Comment: @Akina Do you mean the option "solid block size"? That's greyed out in the packing method I used: zip without compression. The exact settings are: Archive format zip, compression level store, all CPU threads, update mode add and replace, path mode full, no encryption, split to 1500000000 byte files, no manual parameters.

Comment: *Do you mean the option "solid block size"?* Yes. *Archive format zip* Oops... sorry, I was inattentive.

Comment: I fixed my problem! It was indeed a faulty download. Downloading #100, which I had targeted due to being in the right position, calculated from file sizes, didn't help, neither did #96, which I had found to be the last archive I added before the file appeared in the 7zip GUI. But then I re-downloaded all others from 95 to 104 (over night) and that actually fixed it. I'll change my question now to be more about how the error codes are generated and what they mean than about fixing my concrete problem.

Comment: Oh great, Google sent me back to my own, unanswered question. And this time it's a CD that contains the file, so just downloading it again doesn't work.